# How can I clean url's cache?

Tags: url

My Emacs crashed, and now it seems like my `url` cache is poisoned:

```
error in process filter: Opening input file: No such file or directory, c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/ffa50f273d94812bd23dff56a1ca0757 [2 times]
error in process filter: Opening input file: No such file or directory, c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/dc0cdf4984e3f18ede59d4de6a263e14 [2 times]
error in process filter: Opening input file: No such file or directory, c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/ffa50f273d94812bd23dff56a1ca0757 [2 times]
```

How can I force `url` to forget its cache in order to get rid of those messages?

For completeness, here is the accompanying backtrace (with multiline enables and all ellipsis expanded):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Opening input file" "No such file or directory" "c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/ffa50f273d94812bd23dff56a1ca0757")
  insert-file-contents-literally("c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/ffa50f273d94812bd23dff56a1ca0757")
  url-cache-extract("c:/Users/zeta/.emacs.d/url/cache/zeta/http/localhost/ffa50f273d94812bd23dff56a1ca0757")
  url-http-parse-headers()
  url-http-wait-for-headers-change-function(1 124 123)
  url-http-generic-filter(#<process localhost> "HTTP/1.1 304 NOT MODIFIED\15\nServer: Werkzeug/2.1.2 Python/3.9.13\15\nDate: Fri, 02 Jun 2023 10:38:32 GMT\15\nConnection: close\15\n\15\n")
```

Comment: Do you know what package or process created these cache files via `url`?

Comment: @roomworoof Yeah, it's https://github.com/pauldub/activity-watch-mode. It sends a request at the local activity-watch instance whenever I change buffers, which makes Emacs unusable due to the amount of errors when `global-activity-watch-mode` is active. But I'm more interested in a generic solution if possible.

Comment: I've deleted the `~/.emacs.d/url` directory before asking this question but after experiencing the issue :). I have no idea how `url` still thinks there is some cache.

Comment: And given that this is Windows: yes, `request-backend` is set to `'url-retrieve` to ensure that Windows' own `curl` does not break stuff. Everything worked fine until the crash today :/

Comment: My reading of `url-cache.el` indicates that the test for whether a URL is in the cache or not is simply whether the hashed filename *exists*, so it makes little sense that an attempt was then made to go ahead and read a file which would have failed that initial test by virtue of not existing (race conditions aside).  Maybe change `url-cache-directory` and check whether or not the errors still refer to the old directory.  If so, then the url cache probably isn't the problem.  (Something elsewhere may be hanging onto those filenames.)

Comment: Does `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` get you a backtrace?  If so, add that to your question.

Comment: @phils The backtrace is inconclusive, since the stems from the asynchronous callback and doesn't show the actual caller :/

Comment: It does indicate that you have some advice in place for `url-cache-extract` though.  What is that?  From the naming it's old-school `defadvice` so you may need to `M-x rgrep` your config for `url-cache-extract` to find out where that's being defined.

Comment: Actually, that looks weird / maybe an Emacs bug.  It seems strange that when `url-http-generic-filter` runs the cached file wouldn't be present, unless maybe there was a file permissions problem preventing it from being cached in the first place.  I do note that `url-http-parse-headers` isn't testing `url-is-cached` though, but I also don't know whether it has options for proceeding if the cache file isn't there.  I've not looked at this in-depth though, so I'm unsure of what should be happening here.

Comment: Notice the http status code string "HTTP/1.1 304 NOT MODIFIED". From my point of view, what this means, already at the beginning of this backtrace, it is determined that the cache exists and it is already impossible to fall back. So the causal point is the process that passed 2nd parameter `data` to `url-http-generic-filter` with the http status code outside of this backtrace.

Comment: @phils about the "defadvice": nope, that was a red herring by a `restclient` `autoload`. I've adjusted the backtrace after removing the package.

Comment: The crash might have destroyed some other things. For some reason, all Info pages have encoding issues. Or the crash (and the weird behavior now) was only a symptom of a failing drive, no idea :/

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the cache expiration time to 0 to see if `url` is the direct cause? And you can eval `(url-cache-prune-cache)` to force cleanup for the first time.

```lisp
(setq url-cache-expire-time 0)
(url-cache-prune-cache)
```

Comment: Tried this one, didn't work unfortunately, the issue still persists :(. Thanks though